# Admin only folder permissions with WordPress

Tags: wordpress, permissions, admin

I have a folder that I would like it to be only accessible if you are logged into the admin site on wordpress. Right now anybody could go in and activate the functions. Any ideas on how to set this up?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I got your question, you should be more specific. Anyway you can try using `.htaccess` and `.htpasswd` files and implement an Apache HTTP basic authentication.